# Trying to connect to snowflake results in a dead jupyter kernel

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pyarrow

from snowflake.connector import connect as snowflake_connector

```py
from snowflake.connector import connect

SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT  = r'my_account'
SNOWFLAKE_USERNAME = r'my_username'
SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD = r'my_password'


try:
    conn = connect(
            user=SNOWFLAKE_USERNAME,
            password=SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD,
            account=SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT,
            warehouse='W1', 
            database='DB1',
            schema='SC1'
        )
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

This used to work fine, but I must have upgraded something or changed - and now it results in this error (in VS Code's Jupyter Notebooks, and it's also a kernel crash):

```
Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
```

I don't want to use sqlalchemy or pd.read_sql because I'm using the pyarrow format for data transfer.

Any ideas?
Using snowflake connector 2.8.2 And pyarrow 8.0.0

Here is the Jupyter Log traceback:
It seems the issue is with traitlets (I have version 5.4.0)

```
info 15:24:44.741: Started Kernel Python 3.10.7 64-bit (pid: 4548)
info 15:24:44.747: UpdateWorkingDirectoryAndPath in Kernel
error 15:24:47.233: Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: 3221225725, Reason: c:\Users\mkleinbort\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2412: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use 'hmac-sha256' instead of '"hmac-sha256"' if you require traitlets >=5.
  warn(
c:\Users\mkleinbort\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2366: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Bytes is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use 'cd273979-f6a3-426f-b65e-7098ec266fa7' instead of 'b"cd273979-f6a3-426f-b65e-7098ec266fa7"'.
  warn(

info 15:24:47.233: Dispose Kernel process 4548.
error 15:24:47.233: Raw kernel process exited code: 3221225725
error 15:24:47.234: Error in waiting for cell to complete [Error: Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
    at t.KernelShellFutureHandler.dispose (c:\Users\mkleinbort\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1303220346\out\extension.node.js:2:32353)
    at c:\Users\mkleinbort\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1303220346\out\extension.node.js:2:51405
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at y._clearKernelState (c:\Users\mkleinbort\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1303220346\out\extension.node.js:2:51390)
    at y.dispose (c:\Users\mkleinbort\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1303220346\out\extension.node.js:2:44872)
    at c:\Users\mkleinbort\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1303220346\out\extension.node.js:2:2218404
    at t.swallowExceptions (c:\Users\mkleinbort\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1303220346\out\extension.node.js:7:130943)
    at p.dispose (c:\Users\mkleinbort\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1303220346\out\extension.node.js:2:2218382)
    at t.RawSession.dispose (c:\Users\mkleinbort\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.9.1303220346\out\extension.node.js:2:2223490)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)]
warn 15:24:47.235: Cell completed with errors {
  message: 'Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done'
}
info 15:24:47.237: Cancel all remaining cells true || Error || undefined
warn 15:24:47.247: 2022-11-25 15:24:47,237 UTC - WARNING - Unknown command: DISPOSE_INTERRUPT_HANDLE:11:2568
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading from snowflake-connector 2.8.2 to 2.8.1 solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/1342 (where a freeze due to snowflake local cache was described).

The bug currently mentions that 2.8.3 fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I'll upgrade to 2.8.3 soon. Very peeved it broke like that on 2.8.2. I know these things happen, but what an annoying morning it was trying to figure it out.